# How do display a menu dropdown when a screen is resized

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I'm trying to put all my menu links in a dropdown menu when the screen width reduces.

What I have done so far is to write the HTML make-up for the menu dropdown in a form

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post"  class="mobile_form">
    <select name="order" class='mobile_menu'>
    <option value ="home">Home</option>
    <option value ="gallery">Gallery</option>
    <option value ="contact">Contact</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'  class='mobile_menu_button' value='GO'>
    </form>
```

then hid the dropdown for normal screen size using `display:none;` in css.

```
    .mobile_form {
    display: none;
    }
```

Then in the `@media` I'm using to display the dropdown menu where I want it I am using this:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 567px) {
    .mobile_form{
    width: 100%;
    display: block; 
    }
    }
```

When I implement this, the dropdown does not show in normal layout, but it also doesn't show in the resized window.

What mistake I'm I doing ? Can I do this in a better why ?

Thank you.

Comment: You've set it to `display: none` outside of a media query block...  Where do you set the display back to `block`?

Comment: @cimmanon  Thank. I have added display:block; but still does not show in media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu had its display set properly, but the `margin: -47px auto auto auto` inside `#titleBar` was causing it to be hidden off the edge of the viewport.  If I comment it out, the form elements become visible:

http://jsfiddle.net/vCaeG/4/

Comment: I really must advise against using a select element for your mobile navigation.  It would be better to reuse the one list element for both:  horizontal styling for your wider devices, vertical or drop menu styling for narrower devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you PLEASE explain to me more. Thanks

Comment: This is a very crude example:  http://jsfiddle.net/M8VT2/1/ (adjust the size of the result pane)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `display: block` in the media query section otherwise it will still be hidden.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/VYQpd/

Comment: Thank. I have added `display:block;` but still does not show in media query.

Comment: Have added an example. Could you check that works please? If it does then maybe there's something else affecting it.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Here is the website I'm working with [Here](http://goo.gl/hxYfU)

Comment: @user1843335 it is a considerable amount of effort to debug an entire site, please provide a small demo (see: http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for pointing that out.. Here is an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dotman14/vCaeG/)

Comment: That is also working for me. Which browser are you using? Are you using anything like firebug on Chrome developer tools to work out which rules have taken effect at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing bracket ( `}` ) at the end of your media query block.

Comment: That was a typo I fixed and updated the question, but still have the same issue. Here is the website I'm working with [Here](http://goo.gl/hxYfU)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/FepCD)
Note that your media query is applied only when the screen width is **between** 280px and 567px. Maybe what you want to do is just `@media-query (max-width: 567px)` so it will apply to everything **below** 567px width.